# Laravel and DB Escaping

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to do a MYSQL "%like%" query in Laravel and I am seeing some very strange results I do not understand. This might be a Laravel / PHP thing.

Why does this not have the expected results?

```
$string = '19187044491';
$searchString = '\%'.$string.'\%';
dd($searchString);  // this is outputing '\187044491\%'
```

It seems that adding the first "%" sign is doing something to the string and is stripping off characters. Why is this happening? This has never happened to me before. Help someone?

Comment: `%19` is an unused hex value, look at the source of your page and you will see the full string

Comment: So what if it is an unused hex value, why does that matter?

Comment: How can I escape the hex value so I can use it in a query?

Comment: @cmorrissey so you are saying it is using it properly just not rendering it in the browser because it is a hex value?

Comment: that is correct