# PHP and Hex Values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

When I do the following:

```
$string = '19187044491';
$searchString = '\%'.$string.'\%';
```

I get this:

```
dd($searchString);  // this is outputing '\187044491\%'
```

I have been made to understand that this is because '%19' is a hex value   ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146352/laravel-and-db-escaping)) and therefore interpreted as such by PHP. However, I really need to be able to prepend the '%' symbol to the number string to search in a MySQL query. I am trying to something like:
    Select.....where number like '%19187044491%'

and I believe this whole hex thing is causing a problem. I have tried escaping the '%' symbols with backslashes but that seems to be no effect. What should be done to allow the query to work?

Comment: I think this is just an artifact of the [var dumper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html). If you put the variable in the query it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That shouldn't be the case. One thing to remember is that within single quotes backslashes are treated *literally*, and that they only have special meaning inside of double quotes:

```
<?php
$string = '19187044491';
$searchString = '\%'.$string.'\%';
echo($searchString);
?>
```

This produces, not surprisingly, `\%19187044491\%` due to using the wrong quotes. Since `%` isn't special except in a URI context, not PHP in general, you should be fine with this:

```
<?php
$string = '19187044491';
$searchString = "%$string%";
echo($searchString);
?>
```

Where that gives the correct results. Maybe your `dd` function is somehow mangling or interpreting the data incorrectly.